# Nested list performance tuning

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to make a function like these two, but at least an order of magnitude faster in python.
Any tips or tricks?

These functions inputs are nested lists, like: `request_parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, [110, 111, 112, 113, 114]]`

Their output should be: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 110], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 111], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 112], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 113], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 114]]`

OR
a numpy.ndarray:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5 110]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 111]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 112]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 113]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 114]]
```

A unit test is on the way...

input:

```
request_parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, [110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 110]
...
...
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 180]]
```

---

```
import numpy as np

request_parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]


def transform_nested_list(request_parameters: list) -> np.ndarray: 
    """
    Generate np.ndarray from a nested list
    """
    abc_ids = np.asarray(request_parameters[-1])
    #print(abc_ids)

    all_except_id = np.asarray(request_parameters[0:-1])
    #print(all_except_id)

    all_subrequest = np.hstack([all_except_id, abc_ids[0]])
    for element in abc_ids[1:]:
        row = np.hstack([all_except_id, element])
        all_subrequest = np.vstack([all_subrequest, row])
    #print(all_subrequest)
    #print(type(all_subrequest))
    return (all_subrequest)


import copy

def old_transform_nested_list(request_parameters: list) -> list:
    abc_ids = np.asarray(request_parameters[-1])
    all_except_id = (request_parameters[0:-1])

    request_list = []
    subrequest = [all_except_id]
    for single_id in abc_ids:
        #print(single_id)
        subrequest = copy.deepcopy(all_except_id)

        subrequest.append(single_id.astype(int))
        request_list.append(subrequest)
    #print(request_list)
    #print(type(request_list))
    return request_list



import datetime

loop = 10000
start = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(loop):
    transform_nested_list(request_parameters)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
print((end-start).total_seconds())

start = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(loop):
    old_transform_nested_list(request_parameters)

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print((end-start).total_seconds())
```

> >
>   1.111902,
>   0.886634
>   [Finished in 2.2s]

Got a bit better results, but still not good enough:

```
import itertools
def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i

def old_tuple_transform_nested_list(request_parameters: list) -> list:
    abc_ids = np.asarray(request_parameters[-1])

    all_except_id = (request_parameters[0:-1])

    request_list = []
    subrequest = tuple(all_except_id)
    for single_id in abc_ids:
        toupled_subrequest = tuple([subrequest, [single_id]])
        chain = list(itertools.chain(*toupled_subrequest))

        subrequest_list = list(flatten(chain))

        request_list.append(subrequest_list)
    #print(request_list)
    #print(type(request_list))
    return request_list
```

A better version for longer lists:

```
def longer_vector_transformrequest(requestparameters: list) -> list:
    ids = np.asarray(requestparameters[-1]) 
    allexceptid = np.asarray(requestparameters[0:-1])
    subrequest = np.append(allexceptid, 0)

    allsubrequest = np.empty((len(ids),len(requestparameters)))
    for i in range(len(ids)):
        subrequest[-1] = ids[i]
        allsubrequest[i] = subrequest   
    return allsubrequest
```

Comment: Could you explain what these methods do? Could you provide some unit tests?

Comment: Sure, 

They take a nested list - as above noted - request_parameters

And return an other nested list: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14]]

or an numpy.ndarray

[[ 1  2  3  4  5 10]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 11]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 12]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 13]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5 14]]

This is why i left all the print functions in my function in comments so with the input you can easily test. However, I am going to cover this with a unite test in a minute.

Comment: To make it easier to understand that is why i usually use typehints

Comment: Yeh, going to update in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: **Never** use `datetime` to measure performance! There is [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and [`profile/cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) for that. With that out of the way, let's talk about NumPy.

Python in general does not like loops if you want to go fast. NumPy can help you here since a lot of the heavy lifting can be done by the C backend where loops are orders of magnitudes faster. But you have to allow it to play its strengths. [Broadcasting and slicing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html) to the rescue!

```
def slice_transformrequest(request_parameters: list):
    ids = request_parameters[-1]
    allexceptid = request_parameters[:-1]

    # create an empty array of the appropriate size
    transformed = np.empty((len(ids), len(allexceptid)+1))
    # fill all but the ID column
    transformed[:, :-1] = allexceptid
    # now fill the ID column
    transformed[:, -1] = ids

    return transformed
```

Now to the timing part:

```
import timeit

n_loops = 10000
request_parameters = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    [
        110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122,
        123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135,
        136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148,
        149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161,
        162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174,
        175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180
    ]
]

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(n_loops):
    transform_nested_list(request_parameters)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(f"transform_nested_list: {end-start:.3f}s")

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(n_loops):
    old_transform_nested_list(request_parameters)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(f"old_transform_nested_list: {end-start:.3f}s")

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(n_loops):
    longer_vector_transformrequest(request_parameters)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(f"longer_vector_transformrequest: {end-start:.3f}s")

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(n_loops):
    slice_transformrequest(request_parameters)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(f"slice_transformrequest: {end-start:.3f}s")
```

And the results:

```
transform_nested_list:            11.231s
old_transform_nested_list:        8.375s
longer_vector_transformrequest:   0.623s
slice_transformrequest:           0.140s
```

About 4x faster than your fastest solution and about 80x faster than `transform_nested_list`.